# Error while adding event into system calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the below code to add an event to system calendar. System version is iOS 7.1

```
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
if ([store respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)])
{
    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (!granted) { return; }
        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
        [event setTitle:[localStore eventTitle]];
        [event setStartDate:[localStore eventStartDate]];
        [event setEndDate:[localStore eventEndDate]];
        [event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]]; // Error in this line
        [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:nil];
        NSString *savedEventId = [event eventIdentifier]; // return nil
    }];
}
```

Error show in console

```
defaultCalendarForNewEvents failed: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (EKCADErrorDomain error 1013.)"
```

I've already spend few hours to solve this but, I can't. So please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[[EKEventStore alloc] init] autorelease];
if ([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)]) 
{
    // iOS 6 and later
    [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (granted) {
            // code here for when the user allows your app to access the calendar
            [self performCalendarActivity:eventStore];
        } else {
            // code here for when the user does NOT allow your app to access the calendar
        }
    }];
  }
```